# JavaScript 404 Error in IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

My team is building a web application using Jquery. We are coding it with Visual Studio Code and running locally using npm's http-server.

I am trying to publish the application on a local IIS server to demo to our management team. I created a new site on IIS (for this topic, I'll call it "MyWebApplication"). I copied our code to the MyWebApplication folder under wwwroot. Our application, however, is not displaying properly from the server--it only displays some of the text, but the menu we created in JavaScript is not showing up.

Looking at the Network tab in the Chrome debugger, I do have an error:

```
GET http://{iisserver}/scripts/menudata.js?_=1524242509037 404 (Not Found)
```

The initiator is `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4`.

Notice it's looking for the script in the root, `http://{iisserver}/scripts/...`, not in `http://{iisserver}/MyWebApplication/scripts/...`.

If I expand the scripts folder on the Sources tab of Chrome's debugger, menudata.js and one other script related to our menu are not listed. All other .js files in the folder are.

The menu does show up if I copy my scripts folder from MyWebApplication directly to the wwwroot folder, but I shouldn't have to do that.

Are there any ideas on what I can do to make this script accessible from my IIS?

This is IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

**Edit:**
This is a 404 log entry from the IIS log:

```
2018-04-23 14:29:16 x.x.x.x GET /scripts/menudata.js _=1524493754277 80 - x.x.x.x Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/65.0.3325.181+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 187
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Read IIS log files to learn the sub status first.

Comment: @LexLi - Thanks. I have edited my topic to add the log entry for that file. If I'm reading correctly, it's a 404.0 (not found).